# Как считывать docx в android apllication на java

Tags: android, поиск-библиотек, мобильные-приложения

В своем приложении я пробовал Apache POI, но он не рабоатет на android. Есть ли бесплатные библиотеки для считывания docx файлов. Любая информация будет полезной, спасибо 
(Считывать - значит получить только текст из docx файла)

Comment: Поясните что значит "считывание" для вас, пожалуйста.

Comment: Лично не встречал, если гуглинг не помог, поковыряйте OpenSource проекты с поддержкой данного формата данных.

Comment: Считывать - получить только текст из docx файла, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

После долго поиска я обнаружил POI-shadow-all, которая совместима с docx и андроид, ниже приклеплю код для будущих искателей

```
     System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename))) {




            // открываем файл и считываем его содержимое в объект XWPFDocument

            System.out.println("Вижу");
            XWPFDocument docxFile = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fileInputStream));
            XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(docxFile);

            // печатаем все содержимое Word файла
            XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(docxFile);

            //получаем текст из экстратора

            String DocxText = extractor.getText();

            fileNameTextView.setText(filename);//удаляем все копии знаков боле 1
            DocxText.replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\r?\n]]{2,}", " ")
                    .replaceAll("( ?(\r\n)){2,}", "\r\n").replaceAll("( ?\n){2,}", "\n")
                    .replaceAll("^ ", "");



            textViewMain.setText(DocxText);




            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
            file.delete();//удаление фала
            System.out.println(filename);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Извините, а вы код полностью скопировали? Скобка не закрыта.

Comment: Да, действительно. Я изменил код, пользуйтесь